# Chapter 1, Proposition 14 of Lang's number theory - further explanation for normality

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-extensions, separable-extension

Attached is prop 14 on page 15 of Lang's 'algebraic number theory' 2ed. Note, $G_\mathfrak{B} \subset G$ is the subgroup fixing $\mathfrak{B}$
[image]

Can someone perhaps add a sentence or two to explain that $\bar{B}$ is normal over $\bar{A}$.

As I see it, he's taken a separable element and shown that all its conjugates lie in $\bar{B}$. However, for a general element $\bar{y} \in \bar{B}$, we might only say that some power $\bar{x} := \bar{y}^{p^\mu}$ is separable. The minimal polynomial for $\bar{y}$ over $\bar{A}$ will look like
$$
f(X) = h(X^{p^\mu}) = (X^{p^\mu}-\bar{x})(X^{p^\mu}-\bar{x}_2)\dots(X^{p^\mu}-\bar{x}_n).
$$
So, if $(X^{p^\mu}-\bar{x})$ splits into linear factors in $\bar{B}[X]$ why should the others as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wlog assume $K$ is complete $\mathfrak{p}$-adically, thus $(A,\mathfrak{p})$ and $(B,\mathfrak{P})$ are complete DVRs.

Let $P \in A[X]$ be irreducible mod $\mathfrak{p}$, and assume that it has a root in $B/\mathfrak{P}$. Then in $B/\mathfrak{P}$, we can write $P=LQ$ with $L,Q$ coprime polynomials, and $L$ is a power of a linear factor. By Hensel the decomposition lifts to $B$, ie $P=LQ$ with $L,Q \in B[X]$ and $L$ is, mod $\mathfrak{p}$, a power of a linear factor. In particular, one of the irreducible divisors of $P$ is, mod $\mathfrak{P}$, a power of a linear factor.

Now, $P \in A[X]$ is irreducible, so the Galois group acts transitively on the set of its irreducible factors, so all of its irreducible factors are, mod $\mathfrak{P}$, powers of linear factors. Thus $P$ is split in $B/\mathfrak{P}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you assume Wlog that you can take the completions of $A$ and $B$ respectively? Also, I don't think Lang's argument for normality uses the assumption that $\bar{x}$ is separable anywhere...

Comment: I can take completions because they don’t change the residue field extension (which our end result is about), and the field extension remains Galois. I’m not assuming that $\overline{x}$ (what even is it in the argument?) is separable anywhere.

Comment: But is the extension of the corresponding quotient fields still Galois? I.e. those of $\hat{A}_\mathfrak{p}$ and $\hat{B}_\mathfrak{B}$? Or do you not need to use any facts about them? Also, my latter comment was about Lang's proof. He states that $\bar{x}$ is taken to be separable and then shows the irred polynomial splits in $\bar{B}$ but the argument seems to go through even without the separable assumptions.

Comment: Please forgive my unenlightened questions/thinking.

Comment: Yes, I am using the fact that the fraction field of $B_{\mathfrak{P}}$ is Galois over $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$. Why? Because $L$ is the splitting field of a certain separable polynomial $P \in K[x]$, and thus $L_{\mathfrak{P}}$ is a splitting field over $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ of the same $P$.